# Вывод данных с трех таблиц (оптимизация)

Tags: php, mysqli

Сделал простой запрос вывода с 3 таблиц mysql 5.6
Но он очень ужасно тормозит, в таблице tori 3гб, как можно оптимизировать?
Сам запрос такой

```sql
SELECT card, pos, shift_open, local_number, 
       date, amount, tori.item, tori.quantity, 
       tori.receipt_header 
FROM trm_out_receipt_header torh   # к этой таблицы прикрепим две остальные по двум разным условиям совпадения
                                   # 2-ю таблицу по одному условию:
LEFT JOIN trm_out_receipt_item tori  ON (torh.id=tori.receipt_header) 
                                   # 3-ю по другому:
LEFT JOIN trm_out_receipt_payment torp ON (torh.id=torp.receipt_header) 
where torh.card IN ('229456', '229455') 
  and tori.cash_id in ('1005001', '1005004', '201002001', '201002005', '201002001', '201002003', '201002004', '201002005');
```

Висит очень долго и подскажите правильно ли я потом пытаюсь вывести? в [дбфидл](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=3e11e48c968e873eeed25d7704376a2a)

```
<? while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
 echo " <tr><td> {$row['card']}</td>
 <td> {$row['pos']}</td>
 <td> {$row['shift_open']}</td>
 <td> {$row['local_number']}</td>
 <td> {$row['date']}</td>
<td>{$row['amount']}</td>
               <td>{$row['item']}</td>
               <td>{$row['quantity']}</td>
    ";

    
}

?>
```

Сделал так, но запрос очень долго идет, но все же выполняется, в таблице tori 3гб, как можно оптимизировать?

Можно ли сделать вывод двух полей в одну строку? смотрите

[image: https://prnt.sc/11q5lyj]

Explain

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: *в дбфидл* Угу... и ни одного индекса ни в одной из таблиц. Чё б ему не повеситься-то? Причём на самом деле они есть - показанный скриншот EXPLAIN об этом недвусмысленно свидетельствует. [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=64419e69e08c2ae3668e5d9acb1bf506) - там все индексы, теоретически способные ускорить процесс (ну кроме покрывающих). Пробуйте, какие из них могут использоваться на реальных данных. Да. если какое-то поле уникально - все индексы с этим полем также сделать уникальными.

Comment: И ещё. Условие по `tori.cash_id` однозначно превращает `LEFT JOIN trm_out_receipt_item tor` в `INNER JOIN trm_out_receipt_item tor` - замените.

Comment: @Akina поменял ссылку добавил индексы, но смотрите я сначала делал через inner но оно еще дольше ищет

Comment: Тогда см. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=bb223b4a3d9bf3a4b50fef4b796c0301 - и обрати внимание, что на fiddle план твоего запроса на твоей структуре и реальных данных не такой, как на скриншоте.

Comment: @Akina немного не понял, https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=8db00aa5a01c927b3f758c9c49cde909   вроде же есть данные и по запросу выводит, просто одно выводить с полной базы минут 10 ищет

Comment: Так к запросу-то претензий нет - чего ему не то выводить? индексы - они влияют не на результат, а на скорость его получения (при неправильном использовании - бывает, что и не в ту сторону...).

Comment: @Akina в них совершенно не разбираюсь, что надо делать и куда копать?

Comment: @Akina а еще вот вопрос, у меня там выходит больше 50к строк, но их так много не должно быть как так?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT card, pos, shift_open, local_number, 
       date, amount, tori.item, tori.quantity, 
       tori.receipt_header 
FROM trm_out_receipt_header torh   
INNER JOIN trm_out_receipt_item tori  ON (torh.id=tori.receipt_header and torh.cash_id = tori.cash_id) 
LEFT JOIN trm_out_receipt_payment torp ON (torh.id=torp.receipt_header and torh.cash_id=torp.cash_id) 
where torh.card IN ('229456', '229455')
```

torh.cash_id = tori.cash_id   вот где была загвоздка